# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch error in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I get the next error executing this command in Matlab:

```
% dibuji sixmin
x_lim=-2:.1:2; y_lim=-1:0.1:1;
[x(1), x(2)]= meshgrid(x_lim, y_lim);

z = (-exp^(-(x(1) + x(2))))*((sin(3*x(1)))^2)*((sin(3*x(2)))^2);

subplot(2,1, 1)
surf(x(1), x(2), z, 'edgecolor', 'none', 'facecolor', 'interp');
grid on
title('mi_sixmin')

subplot(2,1, 2)
contour(x(1),x(2),z,20)
grid on
```

Anyone could help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be 3 problems with your code.

First, the command `[X, Y] = meshgrid(x_lim, y_lim)` creates two 21x41 matrices and saves them to `X` and `Y`. So, the second line of your code (`[x(1), x(2)]= meshgrid(x_lim, y_lim);`) is attempting to insert a 21x41 matrix into the first element of `x`, and a 21x41 matrix into the second element of `x`. The reason that this does not work is that the each element of the matrix `x` can only fit 1 element. In other words, `x(1)` can only fit a 1x1 matrix. To fix this, replace `x(1)` with `X` and `x(2)` with `Y`. This way, the two 21x41 matrices are saved to their own variables.

Second, note that `exp()` is a function, and not a variable. So, the fourth line of your function should have `exp(-(X+Y))` instead of `exp^(-(X+Y))`.

Third, I believe you are trying to do element-wise operations in that same line. Instead, the code specifies matrix multiplication. To specify element-wise operarations, use `.*` and `.^`. So, the fourth line of your code should be:
`z = (-exp(-(X + Y))).*((sin(3*X)).^2).*((sin(3*Y)).^2);`

So, your edited code should look like this now:

```
x_lim=-2:.1:2; y_lim=-1:0.1:1;
[X, Y]= meshgrid(x_lim, y_lim);

z = (-exp(-(X + Y))).*((sin(3*X)).^2).*((sin(3*Y)).^2);

subplot(2,1, 1)
surf(X, Y, z, 'edgecolor', 'none', 'facecolor', 'interp');
grid on
title('mi_sixmin')

subplot(2,1, 2)
contour(X,Y,z,20)
grid on
```

Comment: Your answer is surely better and precise than mine! +1.

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your script:

- evalaution of `meshgrid`: the output are 2 matrices while you specifying `x(1)` and `x(2)` define 2 scalars
- evaluation of `z`: `exp` does not require `^` it is "already" the exponential; also, since you are working with matrices (generated by `meshgrid`) all the `operand` have to be preceded by `.` (a dot) in order they are applied to each element of the matrices

This is the updated code.

```
x_lim=-2:.1:2; y_lim=-1:0.1:1;
[X, Y]= meshgrid(x_lim, y_lim);

z = (-exp(-(X + Y))).*((sin(3*X)).^2).*((sin(3*Y)).^2);

subplot(2,1, 1)
surf(X, Y, z, 'edgecolor', 'none', 'facecolor', 'interp');
grid on
title('mi_sixmin')

subplot(2,1, 2)
contour(X,Y,z,20)
grid on
```

[image]

Hope this helps.